# C# string trim keeping internal letters

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have a variable string  text containing lets say "ABCDEFGHIJKL".
I want to trim it so string new text = "CDE" in other words keep letters 2 to 4. if A is zero.
How can i do this?

Comment: How does any answer below satisfy - 'if A is zero'?

Comment: I think he means A is zero as in the the index starts at 0 - so A is index 0, B is index 1, C is index 2, etc.  CDE would be 2, 3, and 4 in the given string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're just looking for [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
text = text.Substring(2, 3);
```

Here 3 is the length - characters 2-4 inclusive means 3 characters.

If you're not looking to take a known "slice" of the string (by index and length) please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

**Update**

```
string original = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
string newstring = original.Substring(2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string text = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
string result = text.Substring(2, 3);
```

Note that the second parameter to `Substring()` is the *length*, not the end index.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest reading up on the methods available to the class `System.String`.